# How to save a int in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, app-config, application-settings

I want to save a int like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Score = ScoreInt;
```

So when I reopen the app (it's a clicker game) the int should be the one the player has made.

Comment: Just reverse the process when the app reopens: `ScoreInt = Properties.Settings.Default.Score`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event handler for closing your app and add the call

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

And in the program startup do the assignment like Robert placed in the comments

```
ScoreInt = Properties.Settings.Default.Score;
```